# ClearCase Version Discordance

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

Is there a way to resolve a version discordance through the command line using rcleartool (not cleartool, as I work on a snapshot view).  There is no option for me to use a UI to resolve the issue.

Much appreicated,

Ken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try though, after seing the [**`rcleartool`** man page](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021929), is to check a

```
rcleartool update -username user-name -ser/ver server-url -pas/sword user-password -ove/rwrite
```

An update overwrite might help in this case.

---

Other than that, for what I can see from [About Discordance in ClearCase Remote Client](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21305088) and the Manual [Resolving disagreements (discordance) between client and server](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_maintenance_discord.htm), the process is mainly through the GUI:

[image: file resolution]

Comment: Thanks VonC, but the rcleartool update command has an -overwrite option that will resolve the version discordance.  I found this out right after I asked the question, and it worked.

Comment: @Ken: so the last part of my answer is accurate? (Note: I switched the last part to first)

Comment: ah! I jumped the gun. sorry about that, but yes you're answer was right. thanks again.